# How to make a client in Delphi in order to work with socket.io

Tags: node.js, delphi, socket.io, indy10

I've tried to use Indy 10 components from [here](http://goo.gl/H8rKVv), but socket.io server-side said
`debug: destroying non-socket.io upgrade`

Search in Internet didn't give results.

Do you have ideas?

Comment: That is not even an error, but simply a debug message coming from Indy. I think you can safely ignore it. By the way the title of your question does not really match the question.

Answer (score 2):

First impression: it's like trying to run a combustion engine on water.

When I look into socket.io (and try to figure out how they make things stick over at the node.js-dimension), and if I understand correctly, you should be able to connect to a socket.io server using the (rather new) [WebSockets protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

I don't know if Indy has support for it yet, but the error you get does explain what happens: socket.io expects to get a HTTP request that asks to 'upgrade' to the web-socket protocol over the same connection.

To get something working, I suggest you use TTcpClient and implement a straight-forward WebSockets client, that can first fire the HTTP request with the upgrade-to-websockets request.

(I did a quick search if it's been done already, [but it doesn't look good](http://forums2.atozed.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=25716))

Answer (score 2):

I have a working version of Socket.io on top of my (partial) Indy 10 implementation of websockets:
http://asmprofiler.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/-Other-/IndyWebsocketDemo/

I need to do some cleanup etc and after that, I will upload a new version including socket.io support. But it's not that difficult once you have WS working (see above link) so you can try it yourself in the meantime :)

Comment: however, I gave a link to the same code =) But how to use it I did not understand until the end of. Can you give example code for client-side.

Comment: @artzub: you can run the project and open index.html in a browser (e.g. http://localhost/index.html)

Comment: Client-server as a browser (index.html+socket.io.js) and a server with (node.js+socket.io) — work perfectly. But now I solved the problem, and I'll write decision later, after some test.

Comment: The link is not available any more :-( Does anyone has a solution since then? Especially using ICS or Ararat Synapse but not Indy.

Comment: Last capture at web.archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20141224172234/http://asmprofiler.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/-Other-/IndyWebsocketDemo/